# Array doesn't update from reference

Tags: java

The `line` array doesn't update after the variable `row` has been incremented.

```
private int col = 5;
private int row = 0;

// The array should update according to this defintion
public int [][] line ={{col,row},{col,row+1},{col,row+2},{col,row+3}};

public void drop(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask drop = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            canDrop();
            row++;
            System.out.println(line[0][1]);
            repaint();
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(drop,100,500);
}
```

This code should output the fowllowing lines, but I get lines of zeros instead:

1
2
3
...

Comment: You are printing `line[0][1]` (which is `0`). What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: Well once row has been incremented for it to go up eg. 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: `row++` increments `row`, but it doesn't increment the values in the array. They are primitives and not objects with reference.

Comment: @Henry You aren't printing `row`. You are printing the primitive value `0` from your array. In no way are you updating the *values* in the array.

Comment: To illiustrate this: `int a = 1; int b = a; a++; System.out.print(b);` will print `1`, not `2`.

Comment: how would i update the array ?

Comment: You update the value by writing `line[0][1] = row;`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want to conveniently update the `line` array. However, when you increment `row`, it does not affect your array. The line

```
int [][] line ={{col,row},{col,row+1},{col,row+2},{col,row+3}};
```

creates an array and copies the **values** of `col` and `row`, but it does not store a **reference** to your initial variables `col` and `row`, so that you can update them just by changing their values.

Just create another function:

```
// Updates row in the line array like in your initial definition
public void updateRowInLine(int[][] line, int row) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        line[i][1] = row + i;
    }
}
```

Then call it after `row++`, like `updateRow(line, row);`.